# Display ascx control when button clicked on another ascx control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ascx

I have an aspx page which has 5 image buttons on it. When you click on a button the relevant ascx control appears, and the one that was shown is hidden. These all work fine.

I now have a 6th ascx control on the page which I want to be displayed when a button on one of the other ascx pages is clicked. I have looked online for a solution but not had much luck.

I am using VB.Net for the code behind

Any hints and tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(BTW, I don't approve of Web Forms and "server-side client-event" metaphors like what you're using because they disregard the REStful model that the web is built on, nontheless...)

Create a new event in your UserControls for when their button is clicked, or expose the button directly, then handle this button in your page to display the new, 6ith, ASCX.

This does break encapsulation and expose internals, but from the sounds of things your project is already a mess.